# Why is it a problem to get the return of unique_ptr before assigning to a member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, lifetime, temporary

Why are the results different and the problem occurs in the second method?

1) No error.

```
auto person = getPerson(); // return type : std::unique_ptr<Person>
static_cast<Student*>(person.get())->foo(); // Student inherits Person
```

2) Segmentation fault before entering the function foo()

```
auto person = getPerson().get();
static_cast<Student*>(person)->foo();
```

Comment: What is wrong with just calling `getPerson()->foo()`?

Comment: Because i have to cast person to student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose `getPerson()` returns by-value, then what it returns is a temporary, which will be destroyed after the full expression immediately. Then the raw pointer `person` got from the temporary has been destroyed too (by the temporary `std::unique_ptr<Person>` who owns it), any dereference on it later leads to UB.

In the 1st snippet, you're using a named variable to store the returned `std::unique_ptr<Person>`, it won't be destroyed untill get out of the scope it's declared, then it's fine.

Comment: Correct, this is why it's generally inadvisable to access raw pointers from these types without explicit intention and full understanding of object lifetime (plus a comment in the code to warn of this intent).  Same issue happens with _e.g._ `std::string getSomething() { return "foo"; }` if you were to then try `const char* something = getSomething().c_str();`

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot. I saw it in a book, but I didn't realize it.